# Performing SQL-style operations on a list of lists

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a dynamically generated list of lists akin to the following:

```
[
['author', 'title', 'series', 'series_order', 'genre', 'isbn'],
['Adams, Douglas', 'Mostly Harmless', 'Hitchhiker\'s Guide to the Galaxy', '5', 'Science Fiction', '9780345418777'],
['Simmons, Dan', 'Hyperion', 'Hyperion Cantos', '1', 'Science Fiction', '9780553283686'],
['Herbert, Frank', 'Dune', 'Dune Chronicles', '1', 'Science Fiction', '9780441172719']
]
```

Is there a way to run the following SQL-esque query on it?  Edit: Sorry, I meant that I want to run the Python *equivalent* of the following SQL code on it.

```
SELECT
    author, title, series, series_order, genre, isbn
ORDER BY
    `author` ASC, `series` ASC, `series_order` ASC, `title` ASC;
```

My current plan is to add them all to a temporary SQLite DB on the fly, run the query, and delete the SQLite DB when done.

Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: You could just sort the list of lists by your criteria

Comment: Do you actually need to evaluate some kind of string syntax in order to query this list? Otherwise I would just grab a copy of the list, sort it by the right elements, and then extract the given array indexes for each element. Meaning: *do you actually need the sql*?

Comment: Where do you get this list of lists from, and what are you doing with it subsequently? Would it make sense to put the effort into making it a list of named tuples, dictionaries or even class instances (for which you can define your own rich comparison), instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry, I meant that I want to run the Python *equivalent* of the SQL code on it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's dynamically scraped from the web.

Comment: @Soviero and the rest of my question...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I don't understand...  Please elaborate

Comment: @Soviero what are you planning to do with this list once sorted? How much longer will it "live"? There are other data structures than lists in Python, but it may or may not be worth the effort to convert to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56800/discussion-between-soviero-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension combined with `itemgetter` sorting is SQLesque.

```
from operator import itemgetter

books = [['author', 'title', 'series', 'series_order', 'genre', 'isbn'], ['Adams, Douglas', 'Mostly Harmless', "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", '5', 'Science Fiction', '9780345418777'], ['Simmons, Dan', 'Hyperion', 'Hyperion Cantos', '1', 'Science Fiction', '9780553283686'], ['Herbert, Frank', 'Dune', 'Dune Chronicles', '1', 'Science Fiction', '9780441172719'], ['Brown, Dan', 'The Da Vinci Code', 'Robert Langdon', '2', 'Mystery', '0307474275'], ['Brown, Dan', 'Angels & Demons: A Novel', 'Robert Langdon', '1', 'Mystery', '074349346X']]

sorted([book for book in books[1:] if book[4] == "Science Fiction"], key=itemgetter(0,2,3,1))
>>> [['Adams, Douglas', 'Mostly Harmless', "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", '5', 'Science Fiction', '9780345418777'], ['Herbert, Frank', 'Dune', 'Dune Chronicles', '1', 'Science Fiction', '9780441172719'], ['Simmons, Dan', 'Hyperion', 'Hyperion Cantos', '1', 'Science Fiction', '9780553283686']]

sorted([book for book in books[1:] if book[4] == "Mystery"], key=itemgetter(0,2,3,1))
>>> [['Brown, Dan', 'Angels & Demons: A Novel', 'Robert Langdon', '1', 'Mystery', '074349346X'], ['Brown, Dan', 'The Da Vinci Code', 'Robert Langdon', '2', 'Mystery', '0307474275']]

sorted([book for book in books[1:] if book[2] == "Robert Langdon"], key=itemgetter(0,2,3,1))
>>> [['Brown, Dan', 'Angels & Demons: A Novel', 'Robert Langdon', '1', 'Mystery', '074349346X'], ['Brown, Dan', 'The Da Vinci Code', 'Robert Langdon', '2', 'Mystery', '0307474275']]
```

Comment: Wait, `itemgetter` can accept multiples!?  Why was I not told of this?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

One option to make your code significantly more readable is the [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Book = namedtuple("Book", l[0])
>>> books = [Book(*b) for b in l[1:]]
>>> books[0].author
'Adams, Douglas'
>>> books[1]
Book(author='Simmons, Dan', title='Hyperion', series='Hyperion Cantos', series_order='1', genre='Science Fiction', isbn='9780553283686')
```

Note that I have used the first sub-list (the headers) to define the `namedtuple`'s attributes, and then converted the rest of the sub-lists into the new `Book` objects. Now your sorting becomes much clearer, as you can use `attrgetter` and attribute names instead of `itemgetter` and indices:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> sorted(books, key=attrgetter("author", "series", "series_order", "title"))
[Book(author='Adams, Douglas', title='Mostly Harmless', series="Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", series_order='5', genre='Science Fiction', isbn='9780345418777'), 
 Book(author='Herbert, Frank', title='Dune', series='Dune Chronicles', series_order='1', genre='Science Fiction', isbn='9780441172719'), 
 Book(author='Simmons, Dan', title='Hyperion', series='Hyperion Cantos', series_order='1', genre='Science Fiction', isbn='9780553283686')]
```

You can also perform other SQL-style operations, such as `WHERE`:

```
>>> filter(lambda b: b.author == "Herbert, Frank", books))
[Book(author='Herbert, Frank', title='Dune', series='Dune Chronicles', series_order='1', genre='Science Fiction', isbn='9780441172719')]
```

---

Alternatively, a `Book` class might be appropriate, then you can implement your own [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) and just use `sorted` directly:

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, author, title, series, series_order,
                 genre, isbn):
        self.author = author
        ...

     def __eq__(self, other):
         return (self.author == other.author and
                 self.title == other.title and
                 ...)

     def __lt__(self, other):
         return ((self.author, self.series, self.series_order, self.title) <
                 (other.author, other.series, other.series_order, other.title))
```